# How to do autocomplete textbox in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I tried using this online code from this website (http://jsfiddle.net/sebmade/swfjT/) into my program but still does not show me the output that is similar to his program. As i also want to search by cameraid.
Anyone can help me?

[Angular JS GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPfBB.png)

My jsp file

```
var camListApp = angular.module('camListApp', []).directive('autoComplete',    function($timeout) {
return function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
        iElement.autocomplete({
            source: scope[iAttrs.uiItems],
            select: function() {
                $timeout(function() {
                  iElement.trigger('input');
                }, 0);
            }
        });
};
});
camListApp.controller('Hello', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){ 

$scope.custom = true;
$scope.toggleCustom = function() {
   $scope.custom = ! $scope.custom;

};  
$http.get('http://localhost:8081/camera/list').then(function(response) {
     console.log(response);
        $scope.records= response.data; 
    });
}]);
```

My HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="camListApp">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js">  </script>
<script src="hello.js"></script>

 <title>Image viewers</title>
 </head>

 <body>
 <div ng-controller="Hello">

 <h3>Search:</h3><br>
 <input auto-complete ui-items="records.cameraid" ng-model="searchBox">
 <br>

 <table style="width:55%">
    <thead>
      <tr>

        <th>CamID</th>
        <th>Timestamp</th>
        <th>View Image</th>

      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>

      <tr ng-repeat="record in records | filter:searchBox | orderBy:'+timestamp'">

        <td>{{record.cameraid}}</td>
        <td>{{record.timestamp}}</td>
         <td>{{record.filename}}</td>
        <td><button>View</button></td>

      </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>

  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind to use ui-bootstrap (bootstrap components written for angular), you can use [typeahead directive](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead).

you can install ui-bootstrap by many ways, take a look here [bower, npm etc](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap)

EDIT: for testing purpose you can download all resources from CDN, check plunker at typeahead example page, you can see there these resources:

```
 <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.3.3.js"></script>
 <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Do i need to install bootstrap? As i never try using bootstrap before.

Comment: Hi Alvin, indeed you have to install bootstrap CSS template, but you don't need any knowledge of bootstrap itself. You can just follow example from man page and install bootstrap-ui and use only the typeahead directive

Comment: Hi Stanislav, can i just copy and paste the bootstrap css library into my html file instead?

Comment: Hi Alvin, don't be scared, installing of bootstrap and ui-bootstrap is easy. For example, if you take a look to the typeahead example at plunker site, you will see, that you can simple add link to boostrap.css and add ui-bootstrap script from CDN servers, although i don't recoment this approach at production, you can see how easy is to use ui-bootstrap library

Comment: Yes the typeahead is working with your instruction! Thanks anyway!